# Move network device between Linux network namespaces

Tags: linux, network-namespaces

In Linux, set up 2 network namespaces, `ns1` and `ns2`. `ip netns list` can view the 2 network namespaces.

If I move one network device from Linux root namespace to `ns1` then from `ns1` to `ns2`, then delete `ns2`, I expect that the network device can move back to `ns1`.

The actual result is that `eth1` is back to Linux root network namespace. I'm not sure whether it's as expected.

Here is the detail test scenario:

1. `ip netns add ns1`
2. `ip netns add ns2`
3. `ip link set eth1 netns ns1`
4. `ip netns exec ns1 ip link set eth1 netns ns2`
5. `ip netns del ns2`

**Expected result:** `eth1` will be in `ns1`

**Actual result:** `eth1` is back in Linux root namespace 1

**Question:** is there any method to realize such scenario to make sure device can be back to ns1 not Linux root network namespace 1?

Comment: Make ns2 a child of ns1.

Comment: To overcome this limitation, you could have an event loop running (on the output of) `ip monitor link` to detect the reapparition of the device on the initial net namespace, and immediately cast it to ns1. Interface's name could be different from the former in some cases of renaming or naming conflict.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no way to enforce "physical" network interfaces return to a different network namespace than the so-called "initial" network namespace. Contrary to Patrick's comment, the Linux kernel considers network namespace to be *flat* and thus without any hierarchy (see [ioctl_ns - ioctl() operations for Linux namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ns.2.html), which explicitly mentions only *PID* and *user* namespaces to be hierarchical).

Because there is no hierarchy for network namespaces defined (which would be difficult to apply to IP stacks, addresses, and route tables), Linux has the return-to-home rule which moves network interfaces back into the initial network namespace, that is, the network namespace to which init(1)/PID1 is joined to.

All `ip netns add ...` does is create a new network namespace by calling `unshare()` and then bind-mounts it into `/run/netns/ns1` to keep it floating alive. The next `ip nets add ...` starts anew, mount-binding another network namespace into `/run/netns/ns2`. Two completely unrelated network namespaces.